# How can I best access the BuildContext of a nested widget from a child widget?

Tags: widget, flutter, bottom-sheet

I have a StatefulWidget at the top (let's call it top widget), whose build function looks about like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
    color: // some color,
    theme: // some theme,
    home: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: // some color,
        body: new Builder(builder: (context) {
          _builderContext = context;
          return new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new MaterialApp(
                  color: // some color,
                  theme: // some theme,
                  title: 'title',
                  onGenerateRoute: _onRoute,
                  navigatorKey: _navigatorState,
                  navigatorObservers: observers,
                ),
              ),
              ... etc
```

Now, somewhere in the child widgets generated by _onRoute, I want to bring up a bottom sheet with `showModalBottomSheet(context, ...)`. However, the context passed to showModalBottomSheet needs to be the one from the Builder in the build method above. If I use the context that is available to the child, the sheet pops out at the wrong bottom anchor of my UI. Now, the child can already communicate with the top widget by means of a GlobalKey. However, in another method of the top widget, I can only access its general context. Passing this context into showModalBottomSheet throws a Null Pointer.

After a lot of research and trial and error, the only solution I came up with is to cache the context in the build method ( `_builderContext = context;` ) and then use this cached context to pass it into showModalBottomSheet in my other top widget method:

```
openBottomSheet() {
  if (_builderContext != null) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: _builderContext,
        builder: (context) {
          return // some bottom sheet content;
        });
  }
}
```

For now, this seems to work quite well, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this?

The question could be generalized to how I can access the context in child widgets in general. I tried coming up with an InheritedWidget solution but couldn't really wrap my head around how I could somehow make the Builder an inherited widget and then use that for my problem.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: you should have one and only one `MaterialApp` instance

Comment: I ran into a similar issue regarding modals and InheritedWidget - the solution was to use the 'InheritedWidget' at the root of my application (ie/ from main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

When you already got a `GlobalKey`, isn't `key.currentContext` all you need? Though make sure you test it for not being null like you did with `_builderContext` before calling with it.

Answer (score -1):

If this question was just for using ModalBottomSheet, I would strongly recommend you to use [Flushbar Plugin here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flushbar) for Flutter.

It is quite flexible and you can customize it to a great extent.  You don't have to take care of the context and other stuff right away -- edit it as you need it, and you and also use it anywhere... even if you don't have a scaffold ancestor.  (While using the bottom modal sheet or scaffold it needs a scaffold ancestor).

If this question was just about using context in child widget from the parent widget, I would suggest you to simply pass it to any `class/widget(stateful/stateless)`
as a parameter. It makes everything quite easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the Flushbar plugin. As for the other suggestion: This would of course clutter widget constructors if I needed to pass the context several steps down the hierarchy. Apart from that: Couldn't the context become "stale" at some point? A third problem is that the child widgets are not nested in the build method directly, but are generated via onGenerateRoute. So I would be back to caching the context again anyway.